# Locked out of Gmail account/I have tried too many times

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-recovery

I have been locked out my Gmail account for the last 36 hours because Google complains that I have tried to log in too many ways. I have three different devices home so that would stand a recently yes. I've used every way I can begin packing because I don't remember the password that was reset three days ago.

Answer (score 1):

In Gmail settings, There is one option. "Sign out of all connected devices". Try that way to recover and reset your password.